# Android element alignment - need center vertical

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

How do I make the smiley align center vertically to the right of "Hello world"?

The following is the XML

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Hello world!"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView4"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:background="@mipmap/smiley"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"/>
```

Not sure why `RelativeLayout` is not showing on StackOverflow, but they're in a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Provide how you declared your widgets in your layout's xml file...

Comment: Done. Please take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a specific height of your RelativeLayout container and then position your ImageView centered vertically - `android:layout_centerVertical`
as well as your other views or make their height match_parent.

Comment: Thanks for the help.